# Are there gotchas using varargs with reference parameters

Tags: c++, reference, variadic-functions

I have this piece of code (summarized)...

```cpp
AnsiString working(AnsiString format,...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    AnsiString buff;

    va_start(argptr, format);
    buff.vprintf(format.c_str(), argptr);

    va_end(argptr);
    return buff;
}
```

And, on the basis that pass by reference is preferred where possible, I changed it thusly.

```cpp
AnsiString broken(const AnsiString &format,...)
{
    /* ... the rest, totally identical ... */
}
```

My calling code is like this:

```cpp
AnsiString s1 = working("Hello %s", "World"); // prints "Hello World"
AnsiString s2 = broken("Hello %s", "World");  // prints "Hello (null)"
```

I think this is due to the way `va_start` works, but I'm not exactly sure what's going on.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you look at what va_start expands out to, you'll see what's happening:

```
va_start(argptr, format);
```

becomes (roughly)

```
argptr = (va_list) (&format+1);
```

If format is a value-type, it gets placed on the stack right before all the variadic arguments.  If format is a reference type, only the address gets placed on the stack.  When you take the address of the reference variable, you get the address or the original variable (in this case of a temporary AnsiString created before calling Broken), not the address of the argument.

If you don't want to pass around full classes, your options are to either pass by pointer, or put in a dummy argument:

```
AnsiString working_ptr(const AnsiString *format,...)
{
    ASSERT(format != NULL);
    va_list argptr;
    AnsiString buff;

    va_start(argptr, format);
    buff.vprintf(format->c_str(), argptr);

    va_end(argptr);
    return buff;
}

...

AnsiString format = "Hello %s";
s1 = working_ptr(&format, "World");
```

or

```
AnsiString working_dummy(const AnsiString &format, int dummy, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    AnsiString buff;

    va_start(argptr, dummy);
    buff.vprintf(format.c_str(), argptr);

    va_end(argptr);
    return buff;
}

...

s1 = working_dummy("Hello %s", 0, "World");
```

Comment: Nice explanation of what's going on.

Comment: This is a good example of the proverbial leaky abstraction.  va_start seems like some sort of magic, but really it's just a bit of compiler-approved hackery.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what the [C++ standard, [support.runtime]/[cstdarg.syn] p1.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdarg.syn#1.2) says about `va_start()` (emphasis mine):

> The restrictions that ISO C places on
> the second parameter to the
> `va_start()` macro in header
> `<stdarg.h>` are different in this
> International Standard. The parameter
> `parmN` is the identifier of the
> rightmost parameter in the variable
> parameter list of the function
> definition (the one just before the
> `...`).
> **If the parameter `parmN` is declared with a function, array, or reference
> type,** or with a type that is not
> compatible with the type that results
> when passing an argument for which
> there is no parameter, **the behavior
> is undefined**.

As others have mentioned, using `va_list` in C++ is dangerous if you use it with non-straight-C items (and possibly even in other ways).

That said - I still use `printf()` all the time...

Comment: So what would happen when the varargs argument is the first in the parameter list?

Comment: @Angelorf: If there aren't any formal parameters to the left of the variable argument list, the variable arguments are inaccessible. This is not generally useful, with few exceptions. One such exception is if you need a function signature that matches any argument. This is commonly used as a catch-all implementation in template meta-programming (e.g. when matching generic function pointer types).

Answer (score 4):

A good analysis why you don't want this is found in [N0695 Proposed Changes to C++ `<stdarg>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0695.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

According to C++ Coding Standards  (Sutter, Alexandrescu):

varargs should never be used with C++:

They are not type safe and have UNDEFINED behavior for objects of class type, which is likely causing your problem.

Comment: In this case, it's not the class type issue, since there are only char * types in the va_list.  It's the fact that the argument preceding the list is a reference.

Comment: I agree with your answer, about the macro expansion, it's a good point and probably the actual problem in this case. However, it's still a bad idea to mix it up in your C++ code, as there is nothing to prevent a user from (trying to) pass a std::string in.

Comment: Yup, can't wait for variadic template in C++0x!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my easy workaround (compiled with Visual C++ 2010):

```
void not_broken(const string& format,...)
{
  va_list argptr;
  _asm {
    lea eax, [format];
    add eax, 4;
    mov [argptr], eax;
  }

  vprintf(format.c_str(), argptr);
}
```

Comment: Assumes 32-bit architecture with the add eax,4 ? If so, not portable code.

Answer (score -2):

Side note:

The behavior for class types as varargs arguments may be undefined, but it's consistent in my experience. The compiler pushes sizeof(class) of the class's memory onto the stack. Ie, in pseudo-code:

```
alloca(sizeof(class));
memcpy(stack, &instance, sizeof(class);
```

For a really interesting example of this being utilized in a very creative way, notice that you *can* pass a CString instance in place of a LPCTSTR to a varargs function directly, and it works, and there's no casting involved. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out how they made that work.