# varargs(va_list va_start) doesn't work with pass-by-reference parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there gotchas using varargs with reference parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222195/are-there-gotchas-using-varargs-with-reference-parameters)

Hi, I have a problem with varargs.
Look at my code(Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 2008).

```
#include <stdarg.h>

struct Test { int a; };

void T1(int n, ...) {
 va_list args;
 va_start(args, n);
 char* p = va_arg(args, char*);
 va_end(args);
}

void T2(Test n, ...) {
 va_list args;
 va_start(args, n);
 char* p = va_arg(args, char*);
 va_end(args);
}

void T3(const Test& n, ...) {
 va_list args;
 va_start(args, n);
 char* p = va_arg(args, char*);  // p corrupt!!
 va_end(args);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
 const Test t;
 T1(1, "Test1");
 T2(t, "Test2");
 T3(t, "Test3");
 return 0;
}
```

function T1, T2 work well. But T3 function have a problem. The pointer p doesn't point "Test3". Can't I use va_start with pass-by-reference?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It exhibits the intended behavior in g++, but that does not really mean that much, does it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot use references with `va_start` according to C++ Standard 18.7/3:

> The restrictions that ISO C places on the second parameter to the va_start() macro in header
>    are different in this International Standard. The parameter parmN is the identifier of the
>   rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the ...).
>   If the parameter parmN is declared with a function, array, or reference type, or with a type that is not compatible
>   with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you cannot do that.

NOTE: I saw the first answer which quotes the standard but I believe it is worth showing also my tests.

`va_start` is defined like this:

Visual 6: `#define va_start(ap,v)  ( ap = (va_list)&v + _INTSIZEOF(v) )`

Visual 8: `#define _crt_va_start(ap,v)  ( __va_start(&ap, _ADDRESSOF(v), _SLOTSIZEOF(v), \
                                __alignof(v), _ADDRESSOF(v)) )`

With this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char &rc = c;
    int i;
    int &ri = i;

    printf("char ref:%d\n", sizeof(rc));
    printf("int ref:%d\n", sizeof(ri));

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
char ref:1
int ref:4
```

Since at implementation level references are passed on stack in a similar way to pointers this represents a problem since the size differs (it is because of the macro which computes the size of the type not taking into account that the parameter is actually a reference, which is not constant but depends on actual size of the type).