# va_start - difference between 32 and 64-bit build

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I wrote this code in order to use sprintf-style formatting for std::string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdarg.h>

std::string formatstr(const std::string &fmt, ...)
{
    const char *fmt_s(fmt.c_str());
    std::vector<char> buf(256);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, &fmt);
    auto n = -1;
    while ((n = vsnprintf(&buf[0], buf.size() - 1, fmt_s, args)) == -1)
        buf.resize(2 * buf.size());
    va_end(args);
    std::string text(&buf[0]);
    return text;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string s = "Instrument label: %s";
    std::cout << formatstr(s, "Frequency Generator") << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:**

> Instrument label: Frequency Generator

It works fine in 64-bit builds.

But, as soon as I change the configuration to 32-bit, the VS editor adds the little red squiggly error line under `va_start` and complains: *expression must be an lvalue or xvalue*

[image: VS message]

Is it an error that my 64-bit build works? Or an error in Visual Studio that it doesn't for 32-bit? Is there some fundamental difference?

Comment: Is it just an intellisense error or do you actually get a compiler error? What if you close and reopen the project with 32-bit already selected?

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's not just intellisense. It actually won't let me compile it in 32-bit. I just tried closing and reopening, but it didn't help. Also, the project is new and minimal - I just made it to test this code (for this question).

Comment: @nvd Ok, I concede that it can be construed as a duplicate. It is odd though, that it works fine in 64-bit builds. I've actually been using it for a while, and only just now tried it in a 32-bit build.

Comment: What's wrong with using C++ style `operator<<` or a variadic template? That would be much safer than trying to use printf style.

Comment: You can't call vsnprintf twice with the same va_list object, because "As these functions invoke the va_arg macro, the value of ap after the return is unspecified." Maybe Windows lets you get away with that, but the code won't be portable. Also, since VS2015, `vsnprintf` conforms to C99; it no longer returns -1 if the buffer is too short. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx#Return%20Value

Comment: @rici Glad you pointed that out. I wrote it when I was using VS2012, and you're right, my resizing loop indeed no longer appears to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `va_start(args, &fmt)` with `va_start(args, fmt)`

The documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/) does not indicate that a pointer to the argument is required, instead this should be name of the argument preceding the variable arguments: `...`

Edit: And also see [varargs(va_list va_start) doesn't work with pass-by-reference parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184401/varargsva-list-va-start-doesnt-work-with-pass-by-reference-parameter)

So in order to fix it, you could use a pointer instead of a reference for `fmt`, which give this "fix" (that you may not like it...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdarg.h>

std::string formatstr(const std::string *fmt, ...)
{
    const char *fmt_s(fmt->c_str());
    std::vector<char> buf(256);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    auto n = -1;
    while ((n = vsnprintf(&buf[0], buf.size() - 1, fmt_s, args)) == -1)
        buf.resize(2 * buf.size());
    va_end(args);
    std::string text(&buf[0]);
    return text;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string s = "Instrument label: %s";
    std::cout << formatstr(&s, "Frequency Generator") << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This will get rid of the warning in the editor, but won't compile.

Comment: @BlairFonville What is the compiler error exactly ?

Comment: It does require a pointer. If the arugment to the function were "const char *fmt" then va_start(args, fmt) would work fine.

Comment: You mean the compiler error for my code, or yours?

Comment: I need the compiler error, with the "fix" that I provided

Comment: vadefs.h(151): error C2338: va_start argument must not have reference type and must not be parenthesized

Comment: @BlairFonville See my edit for a "fix", which I do not really like, but it will work...

Comment: Yep, that's awesome - thanks. I should point out that you are now passing a pointer. So, I'm not sure your first few lines are valid.

Comment: Actually, it does make sense. I see it now. Thanks again.

Comment: @BlairFonville I am not passing a pointer to the argument, but the argument itself (I used the argument name without any parenthesis, ...) which is in this case a pointer yes :-) So I think that the beginning of my answer is still valid. It may works with some compiler, it really depends on how va_start() is implemented

Comment: Yes, just got that.