# C++ Variable Arguments and vsprintf

Tags: c++, string, printf, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a few wrappers for the standard `sprintf` function from `cstdio`. However, I'm having some weird behaviour and access violation crashes when running my program. I've simplified the problem and reproduced it on the code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

std::string vfmt(const std::string& format, va_list args)
{
    int size = format.size() * 2;
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    while (vsprintf(buffer, format.c_str(), args) < 0)
    {
       delete[] buffer;
       size *= 2;
       buffer = new char[size];
    }

    return std::string(buffer);
}

std::string fmt(const std::string& format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    std::string res = vfmt(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = fmt("Hello %s!", "world");
    printf(s.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces a memory access violation when calling `vsprintf` in `vfmt`. However, when I change `fmt`'s function signature from `fmt(const std::string& format, ...)` to `fmt(const char* format, ...)`, I no longer crash, and everything works as expected. Why exactly is this happening?

Why is it that changing the type of the `format` parameter from `const std::string&` to `const char*` solves the issue? Or does it only appear to be solved?

Comment: @dirkgently No, that while loop is not for parsing the `args`. It's calling `vsprintf` and checking if the result string fits the buffer. If not, it resizes the buffer and tries again until it does.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the unsafe `vsprintf` instead of `vsnprintf`, or any of its C++ replacements?

Comment: Ah yes, I realized that about 5 mins after posting. My bad. :/

Comment: there is bypass for this error : `#define _CRT_NO_VA_START_VALIDATION` some people have seen this error starting to compile with VS2015, previously no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a reference type as an argument to va_start. That's why changing to `char*` works, and so would leaving the `string` but without the `&`. Using a reference messes up the magic that is done in order to obtain the variable number of arguments.

See [Are there gotchas using varargs with reference parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222195/are-there-gotchas-using-varargs-with-reference-parameters).

Comment: That's it. Makes sense too. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Good catch.  Unfortunately, switching to a pointer would require changing the public interface, not just the helper function.  :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  I mean, the version you say "works".

`vsprintf` doesn't let you detect when the buffer passed in is too small, since it doesn't know how big it is.  It will happily write over whatever objects follow your buffer.  This may cause an access violation, it may crash your program sometime later, it may generate an e-mail to your mother with racy pictures attached.  This is *undefined behavior*.  **Your reallocate-and-retry loop is useless.**

You may have better luck with `vsnprintf`, which **does** know how big the buffer is, if your library provides it.